# Manipulating Values in Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, class, dictionary

So I have a dictionary whose index is an int, and whose value is a class that contains a list of doubles, the class is built like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<double> MyList = new List<double>();
}
```

and the dictionary is built like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, MyClass> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, MyClass>();
```

I populate the dictionary by reading a file in line by line, and adding the pieces of the file into a splitstring, of which there is a known number of parts (100), then adding the pieces of the string into the list, and finally into the dictionary. Here's what that looks like:

```
public void DictionaryFiller()
{
    string LineFromFile;
    string[] splitstring;
    int LineNumber = 0;
    StreamReader sr = sr.ReadLine();

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        LineFromFile = sr.ReadLine();
        splitstring = LineFromFile.Split(',');

        MyClass newClass = new MyClass();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            newClass.MyList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(splitstring[i]));
        }

        MyDictionary.Add(LineNumber, MyClass);

        LineNumber++;
    }
}
```

My question is this: is I were to then read another file and begin the DictionaryFiller method again, could I add terms to each item in the list for each value in the dictionary. What I mean by that is, say the file's 1st line started with 10,23,15,... Now, when I read in a second file, lets say its first line begins with 10,13,18,... what I'm looking to have happen is for the dictionary to have the first 3 doubles in its value-list (indexed at 0) to then become 20,36,33,...

Id like to be able to add terms for any number of files read in, and ultimately then take their average by going through the dictionary again (in a separate method) and dividing each term in the value-list by the number of files read in. Is this possible to do? Thanks for any advice you have, I'm a novice programmer and any help you have is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Replace

```
newClass.MyList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(splitstring[i]))
```

with

```
newClass.MyList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(splitstring[i]) + MyDictionary[LineNumber].GetListOfDouble()[i])
```

and then replace

```
MyDictionary.add(Linenumber, Myclass)
```

with

```
MyDictionary[linenumber] = MyClass
```

Just makes sure that the MyDictionary[LineNumber] is not null before adding it :)

Something like this would work

```
If(MyDictionary[LineNumber] == null)
{
  MyDictionnary.add(LIneNUmber, new List<double>());
}

If(MyDictionary[LineNUmber][i] == null)
{
    return 0;
}
```

My solution does not care about list size and it done at reading time not afterward, which should be more efficient than traversing your Dictionary twice.

Comment: one issue, in your second line of code I'm running into a problem that says "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.MyClass'". Any clue why that is happening?

Comment: Sorry it should be something like this : 
MyDictionary[LineNumber].GETLISTOFDOUBLE()[i]);

Forgot it was a class and not directly a list

Comment: thanks, it turns out you actually just need to reference the list directly, so you can change GETLISTOFDOUBLE to MyList, if youd like. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
var current = MyDictionary[key];
for(int i = 0; i < current.MyList.Length; i++)
{
   current.MyList[i] = current.MyList[i] + newData[i];
}
```

Given both lists have same length and type of data.

You can get the custom object by key of the dictionary and then use its list to do any operation. You need to keep track of how many files are read separately.